# Escolher tabela de base de dados para utilizador logado

Tags: php, mysql

Pretendo escolher apenas 1 tabela de uma base de dados, dependendo do utilizador que está logado no website.
Quero isto porque estou a fazer uma página de gestão de conta para os utilizadores do site. Nessa página tenho um calendário (fullcalendar) onde vou buscar os eventos a uma tabela.

O que eu quero fazer é uma tabela para cada utilizador, e arranjar uma *query* que me faça o `select` da tabela certa para mostrar os eventos desse utilizador apenas.
O meu código atual está a selecionar todos os eventos de uma tabela apenas:

```
<?php

 $json = array();

 $requete = "SELECT * FROM eventos ORDER BY id";

 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', 'root', '');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
 exit('Impossivel conectar à base de dados.');
 }

 $resultado = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

 echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

Comment: Não precisas de fazer uma tabela para cada utilizador. Podes fazer uma tabela com chave dupla `user_id` e `eventos_id`. E uma tabela dá para todos.

Comment: Não sei se percebi: o objetivo é inserir uma variável em cada evento (user_id) para distinguir quem é o dono desse evento? E a variável eventos_id seria para quê?

Comment: Não seria nada que já vi que tu já tens um `id` na tabela eventos.

Comment: E o código ficaria algo como $requete = "SELECT * FROM eventos where user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'"; ?

Comment: Sim, ai ias buscar os eventos desse utilizador.

Comment: hm, estive a experimentar mas a minha sessão está criada com o username e não o user_id. Nesse caso em vez de usar o user_id para distinguir os donos dos eventos, posso usar o username

Comment: Se ele for único podes. Mas cuidado que a pesquisa por username pode ser mais demorada. O ideal era mesmo acrescentares na sessão o id. Ou então criar um índice para a coluna de username na tabela de utilizadores.

Comment: Referes-te a este tipo de Indice? Nunca usei isto ( só uso MYSQL à 1 mes), para que serve? http://i.imgur.com/asWPz3r.png

Comment: É isso mesmo. Sendo MySQL ou outro motor de Base de Dados a ideia é a mesma.

Answer (score 2):

Podes resolver isso tendo duas tabelas, uma de utilizadores e uma de eventos

Tabela de utilizadores

```
| id         | nome        | ...
|------------|-------------|-----
| 1          | joaquim     |         
| 2          | albano      |      
| ...        | ...         |
```

Tabela de eventos

```
| id         | user_id     | evento             | ...
|------------|-------------|--------------------|----
| 1          | 1           | evento 1 do user 1 | 
| 2          | 1           | evento 2 do user 1 !  
| ...        | ...         | ...                |
```

Podes fazer isso com chave estrangeira em que `user_id` é chave estrangeira do `id` do utilizador.